# Unexpected found nil will unwrapping an Optional value occurs when setting a property of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, option-type

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    initializeFetchedResultsController()
}
```

The line `tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` executes fine, but the next line breaks apparently from trying to unwrap an optional:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

[image]

Comment: Try to disconnect and connect IBOutlet!

Comment: There must be some other problem because if your first line with tableView executes that means tableView is not nil, so there nothing as such in this line  tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() to make it crash, just recheck it.

Comment: I guess you have to use the designated initializer `UIView(frame:)`

Comment: I tried disconnecting/reconnecting the IBOutlet as well as using the initializer with the frame: tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero).

Neither fixed the unwrapped optional being nil; I still don't know what is being nil

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem. Upon setting a tableview footer programmatically it seems reloadData is called, the table begins looking for data, and it calls numberOfSectionsInTableView before viewDidLoad completes. If you are setting your table data in viewDidLoad after assigning a tableView footer the data is nil and crashes the app.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code to the viewWillAppear, which is invoked when all outlets are already set. However the prevent multiple UIView instantiation while popping back to your tableView put the code within if {}:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if self.tableView.tableFooterView == nil {
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the reason footerview not exist in viewdidload

Comment: at time of viewDidload called all outlets already initialized

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to be your main view controller, there is the possibility that its viewDidLoad() function is being called before the application singleton has been assigned the appDelegate.  (this depends on how Apple programmed the initialization sequence of the application)

Depending on optimization settings, it is not always the line that causes the error that is highlighted in the debugger.   One way to make sure is to remove the line and, if the error remains, you'll know that it was something farther down that caused the problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am certain that it was that line because before you posted this answer, and in fact when I posted this question, obviously my code was working before I added that exact line

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that.  I tried to reproduce the problem in various places where I use UITableviews in my app but could not get an error.   There must be something else that the assignment of tableFooterView triggers somehow and is signaled at that line.   Can you provide more information ( cells/views already in the table view,  which methods of the delegate have you implemented, is the delegate connected in IB or in code, are there any constraints ...)

Comment: I was trying to step into that line of code with F7 and step into instruction.  I believe the delegate is connected in the storyboard.  There is essentially a single cell in the table view at the moment, because I reinstalled my app and the data was cleared, but before there were many cells

Comment: I just realized I was focusing too much on the error and not enough on your needs.  Perhaps adding the footer view in IB instead of adding it by code would remove the roadblock so you can move forward (or discover new information).

Comment: I ended up doing that yesterday, and it did do what I was looking for